# Centering a div that has float left set

Tags: html, css

So im feeling pretty stupid that I can't figure this out but my problem is as following:

I got a footer and inside the footer I have 2 divs, 1 containing a Facebook image and 1 containing copyright text. What I want to do is float them next to each other, but align the Facebook image to the left and the text to the center.

Html:

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div id="facebook"><img src="img/FB-f-Logo__blue_29.png" alt="facebook link"></div>
    <div id="footerText"><p>© Copyright 2013. All Rights reserved.</p></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```css
#footer {
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#facebook {
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
}

#footerText {
    float:left;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
}
```

Comment: I have interpreted that you either want to: 1) center both the image and text in the footer while floating them or 2) float both to the left but have the text aligned center. Both cases requires an entirely different approach. which want do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give both divs an additional "wrapper" within the footer: http://jsfiddle.net/y9xpA/

```css
#wrap {width: 400px; margin: auto;}
```

Comment: This is the first answer I checked and it worked great after some tweaking! Im sure the other answers are good to but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your text in `#footerText` will not be centered because `#footerText` doesn't have a specified width. Its width is currently `auto`, which is default, so it will shrink to the width of the text inside; neither `text-align:center` or automatic side margins will fix this, as I can see you've tried.

If you want `#facebook` floating *all the way* to the left of the footer, you can give the remaining width of the footer to `#footerText`:

```css
#footerText {
    float:left;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 931px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using absolute position to move the Facebook div out of the flow of the page and to the left, then giving the footer text a left margin equal to the facebook div's width and centering it:

```
#footer {
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
#facebook {
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
#footerText {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto 20px 29px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m3ZSq/)

Comment: This assumes a static (rigid) height. That is not always the case; though footers are usually the same height.

Comment: @ProfileTwist, the OP clearly indicated that the footer has a height of 50px.  The downvote is out of line, as my answer conforms to the OP's stated requirements.

Comment: I overlooked the height requirement and now I can not take back my downvote as it is locked.

Comment: I will always consider absolute positioning as a second-tier solution when floats and static positioning will more than suffice the requirements. This one, secluded example you provide, is an exception to this rule because the footer is so small and likely not to contain any other information. However, I think its good for future readers to know that as powerful as absolute positioning may be, it is not the most effective solution because _content is removed from the document's flow_ ... especially when floats and/or static positioning is more than sufficient.

Comment: There you go. Hope my Karma is restored.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be much, much easier to just give the `#footer` a `text-align:center` and set the other elements inside it to `display:inline`. Check out a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pUKwJ/

Answer (score -1):

```css
#facebook:
{
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
}
#footer-text
{
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: center;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing in CSS as 'v-align'